# sam local start-lambda - how to send send s3 event to sam local endpoint

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I can invoke a local lambda http endpoint (sam local start-lambda), but how do I trigger that lambda endpoint with a (mock) AWS event (s3, etc.) like I can when using the Dockerized lambda environment (sam local invoke -e event.json myLambdaFunction)?

I want to trigger an s3 event on the locally running lambda endpoint just like I can on a lambda deployed to AWS.

Answer (score 5):

First you generate the sample function payload:

```
sam local generate-event s3 put --bucket bucket-name --key key-name > event.json
```

Then you invoke your function with the generated payload:

```
sam local invoke -e event.json function-name
```

Alternatively, the `generate-event` output can be piped directly as input to the `invoke` command:

```
sam local generate-event s3 put --bucket bucket-name --key key-name |
sam local invoke -e - function-name
```

More info is in the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-generate-event.html).

Comment: generate-event needs the s3 verb **put** as well.  Corrected version:

`sam local generate-event s3 put --bucket bucket-name --key key-name > event_file.json`

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the answer.